# Setting filenames and paths of auto-pst-pdf

Tags: auxiliary-files, auto-pst-pdf

When one has a lot of documents for a single project, it gets important not to lose the overview. I use `\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}` together with pdflatex and it works fine in principal. However, the images are always created in the same folder as my .tex files (with the suffix "-pics.pdf") and I seem not able to change this default behavior. This makes my main folder really crowded. My question is: **How can I change where my "temporary" .pdf files are saved and how they are called when I use `\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}`?**

For `\usepackage{pst-pdf}` there exists an option `\edef\PDFcontainer{...}`, with which one can define such a file name and path. Nevertheless, this does not work for the auto version, where there appear to be other definitions like `\edef\pics{...}` and `\def\suffix{}`, but those dont work as expected. I am sure it is pretty easy to solve my question, but I do not seem to get it.

Additional note: The option `\usepackage[cleanup={log,dvi,ps,pdf}]{auto-pst-pdf}` deletes all temporary files *except* for the temporary .pdf files "*-pics.pdf".

Comment: how can your main folder "really crowed" when you have _one_ additional file?

Comment: I have a small workaround: add `\makeatletter\app@remove@container\makeatother` after every `\end{pspicture}`. It deletes the temporary files of this picture. This command seems not to be evoked after the compilation and I consider it a bug that the cleanup does not work properly.

Comment: the cleanup is the default and there will be _no_ additional file other than the container file.

Comment: Right, but I dont want a container file. How can I get auto-pst-pdf to delete this file automatically?

Comment: use alternatively `xelatex` then you do not need a container. However, the sense of keeping the file is that you do not need to create with every LaTeX run the images. After the first run, you can use the option `inactive`.

Comment: Then - how can I change the location of the container file?

Comment: see my answer how it can be done

Comment: I cant write comments? Thanks for editing this into a comment to [enter link description here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36414/setting-filenames-and-paths-of-auto-pst-pdf/36428#36428). Your answer does not work for me, no .pdf container is generated, no image is shown.

Comment: `crop=off` should do the trick. `pdfcrop` didn't know anything about the output path

Comment: sorry, still no output file when using `\usepackage[crop=off,pspdf={-sOutputFile=/tmp/\jobname-pics.pdf}]{auto-pst-pdf}` and `\edef\PDFcontainer{/tmp/\jobname-pics.pdf}`. The folder "tmp" exists of course. The error message "File ..../tmp/...-pics.pdf not found." is being shown.

Comment: please controll if the file is in `/tmp/` which is true for me.

Comment: no, it is not. okay, so my problem must lie somewhere else.

Comment: Did you find the solution to your problem? I am also interested.

Answer (score 2):

For example if the file should be saved in `/tmp/`

```
\usepackage[pspdf={-sOutputFile=/tmp/\jobname-pics.pdf}]{auto-pst-pdf}
\edef\PDFcontainer{/tmp/\jobname-pics.pdf}
```