# Compilation issue with pdfLaTeX and auto-pst-pdf

Tags: pdftex, compiling, pstricks, auto-pst-pdf

I am using a lot of png/jpg images in a document, so I decided to use **pdfLaTeX**. The main issue of this approach is that **PSTricks** is not directly supported. Since I found a package (**auto-pst-pdf**) supposed to solve this, I gave it a go. But I found a problem.

Let's take a simple example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}
\usepackage[on]{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

This is a test file
\newline
\newline
\begin{pspicture}(-5.25,-5.25)(5.25,5.25)
  \pscircle*[linecolor=cyan]{5}
  \psgrid[subgriddiv=0,gridcolor=lightgray,gridlabels=0pt]
  \Huge\sffamily\bfseries
  \rput(-4.5,4.5){A} \rput(4.5,4.5){B}
  \rput(-4.5,-4.5){C}\rput(4.5,-4.5){D}
  \rput(0,0){auto-pst-pdf}
  \rmfamily
  \rput(0,-3.8){PSTricks}
  \rput(0,3.8){\LaTeX}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

If we try to compile this file in its folder (with output folder = `build`):

```
pdflatex -shell-escape -output-directory=build test.tex
```

Everything works well, and the resulting PDF is moved to `result`. Now, let's imagine that we have a folder with the following structure:

```
-- root (Makefile)
 |___ src (tex files)
 |___ build (everything generated by pdfLaTeX)
```

If we call make from the root folder, the following command will be executed:

```
pdflatex -shell-escape -output-directory=build src/test.tex
```

Even though the only difference is the location of the tex file, this does not work: the temporary image files (dvi, ps, pdf) are not compiled, and the resulting document does not get its figure.

I have tried using some auto-pst-pdf options:

```
\usepackage[on,
            latex={-out-directory=. -jobname=test-pics test.tex},
            dvips={-o test-pics.ps test-pics.dvi},
            pspdf={-dAutoRotatePages=/None test-pics.ps test-pics.pdf},
            crop=off
           ]{auto-pst-pdf}
```

But this does not work so far, and I do not know if that is the right way to do this. Has anyone faced any similar problem, and if yes, how did you solve it?

Comment: I found a similar problem: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36414/setting-filenames-and-paths-of-auto-pst-pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are starting `pdflatex` in `root`. So this is the current directory. `auto-pst-pdf` will at first call `latex --jobname=test-autopp test` to generate a `test-autopp.dvi` with the pictures. This first step will already fail as `latex` obviously can't find `test` in the current directory `root` and has no idea that it should look in `scr`.

You should always start `pdflatex` in the directory of the main file. Everything else can get quite confusing.

Comment: Indeed, which is why I tried to use some custom commands in `\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}`, but it still fails for some reason. If in `src`, I call `pdflatex -shell-escape -output-directory=../build test.tex`, the file is properly generated, the only issue is that the temporary pdf is located in `src` too (I like having a clean `src` folder). Still, a temporary folder option to pdflatex would solve this problem I guess.

Comment: @BenC It doesn't help to add options which tells LaTeX/dvips where to *write* something or how to name the *output*. The LaTeX call of `auto-pst-pdf` has problems to find its *input*. It's expecting it in the current directory and there is no option to change this. You would have to hack the code. I suggest to write some batch file which either moves all you source files to some temporary folder before compilation, or which cleans up you scr-folder after compilation.

Comment: Theoretically, using `auto-pst-pdf` options to change the output directory, and `\graphicspath` to use that output directory instead of the current one should be doable, because `pst-pdf` relies on `\includegraphics` and `auto-pst-pdf` is just a wrapper. Does that make sense?

Comment: No. The problem is not that (pdf)latex can't find the graphic, but that latex can't find your main file and so can't even start to generate the graphic.

Comment: If I launch `pdflatex` from the `src` folder, `latex`, `dvips`, `ps2pdf` and `pdfcrop` all find the files, now I am just trying to move the temporary files to the `build` folder (`test-pics.pdf` that remains for instance), since that's the only thing possible apparently.

Answer (score 2):

insert into your preamble:

```
\graphicspath{{./}{./src/}{./build/}}
```

Comment: This did not work for me. `\graphicspath` is used by the latex compiler to find the pictures, but will not help for this compilation step, will it?

Comment: it should work with `\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}`